# Setup Jenkins Blue Ocean plugin via groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-blueocean

I'm playing with the Blue Ocean plugin and my goal is create a Jenkins installation from the scratch fully configured with a job linked to a Github repository, all that done in an set of init scripts written in Groovy.
I have all the information needed beforehand to configure the pipeline:

- Github Token
- Github Orgs
- Github Repository (contains a Jenkinsfile on the root directory)

I already found some pieces but the full picture is not complete/working. Here is where the magic seems to start [validateAndCreate](https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/blob/c67152f40d9d1455ccdc92d2df223baf0c3374cf/blueocean-github-pipeline/src/main/java/io/jenkins/blueocean/blueocean_github_pipeline/GithubScm.java#L246).

My setup is:

- Jenkins 2.121.2
- Blue Ocean 1.7.2

Am I in the right path? Can someone shed light here?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Do you want to create a Jenkins job using some script? Did you try using JOB DSL? Shall the job itself be a script (Jenkins Pipeline)? What does it have to do with Blue Ocean? Blue Ocean is just a different UI, what do you need to script there?

Comment: I want to create a Jenkins installation from the scratch with Blue Ocean installed and configured (pointing to a given repository on Github) via init scripts (Groovy). My Github repository has a Jenkinsfile on the root directory.

Comment: So I assume you want to create the whole Jenkins instance using some scripting with specific plugins pre-installed?

Comment: Exactly! The end goal is being able to automagically create several Jenkins installations with the same setup BUT pointing to different Github repositories.

Comment: Shall those instances run inside some virtual containers? In that case I'd propose you using docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/.

Comment: Yes, they are already running on docker but that isn't the current issue

Comment: In that case I think I would be helpful to clarify your question. Please include all the information written in the comments above and make clear what is not working. I'd be also curious how this all relates to the link you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days trying here is the final solution https://github.com/tmoreira2020/jenkins-blue-ocean, it meets my requirement completely.